# when i click to Sign up it redirects me to Sign up page but Content is Not Visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm crating Block-chain based e-voting system project as my last year project in which in the sign in page whenever I click on "Sign up" button it redirect me to signup page but the content of this page is not visible. It shows only plane white screen. I have tried all possible solutions but none of then work. Let me know where is my problem.

## Login.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";    
import './styles.css';

const Login = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ voter_id: "", password: "" });
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/signin";
            const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data);
            window.location = "/";
        } catch (error) {
            if (
                error.response &&
                error.response.status >= 400 &&
                error.response.status <= 500
            ) {
                setError(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={'login_container'}>
            <div className={"login_form_container"}>
                <div className={"left"}>
                    <form className={"form_container"} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <h1>Log in</h1>
                        {/* <h1>Login to Your Account</h1> */}
                        <input
                            type="voter_id"
                            placeholder="Voter_id"
                            name="voter_id"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.voter_id}
                            required
                            className={"input"}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.password}
                            required
                            className={"input"}
                        />
                        {error && <div className={"error_msg"}>{error}</div>}
                        <Link to="/">
                        <button type="submit" className={"green_btn"}>
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                        </Link>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className={"right"}>
                    <h1>New Here ?</h1>
                        <button type="button" className={"white_btn"}>
                    <Link to="/Signup">
                        Sign Up
                    </Link>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

## Signup.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import './styles.css'

const Signup = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const navigate = Redirect();

    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/signup";
            const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
            navigate("/login");
            console.log(res.message);
        } catch (error) {
            if (
                error.response &&
                error.response.status >= 400 &&
                error.response.status <= 500
            ) {
                setError(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={"signup_container"}>
            <div className={"signup_form_container"}>
                <div className={"left"}>
                    <h1>Welcome Back</h1>
                    <Link to="/login">
                        <button type="button" className={"white_btn"}>
                            Sign in
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className={"right"}>
                    <form className={"form_container"} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <h1>Create Account</h1>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="voter_id"
                            name="voter_id"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.voter_id}
                            required
                            className={"input"}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.password}
                            required
                            className={"input"}
                        />
                        
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="password_confirmation"
                            name="password_confirmation"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.password_confirmation}
                            required
                            className={"input"}
                        />
                        {error && <div className={"error_msg"}>{error}</div>}
                        <button type="submit" className={"green_btn"}>
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Signup;
```

## index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/css/animate.min.css";
import "./assets/scss/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss?v=2.0.0";
import "./assets/css/demo.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";

import Login from "views/Login/Login";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";
import Signup from "./views/Signup/Signup";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
       <Route path="/signup" exact element={<Signup/>} />
       <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
       <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/Voting_List" />
      <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

## Output

[image: Signin Page:-]

[image: Signup Page:-]

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What ***specific*** versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed and used? And do you happen to be rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Can you provide any other debugging details you may've checked? I don't path casing should matter, but the route is `path="/signup"` but you are linking to `"/Signup"`. Try making the casing match in case it does actually matter for some reason.

Comment: no there is no error in console. i'm using 5.3.4  version of dom. what is that react.strictmode?

Comment: [React.StrictMode](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) is a React component that is helpful in debugging your app.

Comment: ohkk.....so do you have any idea how to fix it

Comment: Oops, don't know how I missed on the first couple code reads. Yes, I see the issue now and have answered below.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the new `react-router-dom@6` `Route` component API with what should be the v5 props. RRDv5 `Route` component doesn't have an `element` prop.

`element={<Signup/>}` should be `component={Signup}`.

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
      <Redirect to="/admin/Voting_List" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```